# dll not loading after SVN update

Tags: visual-studio, svn, dll

In my company we've been saving our source code into SVN after making changes. We don't save dlls in the SVN, but when we do a build, they get added to the correct location somehow. I've never questioned how this happens before.

Now we have a new dll we're using from a 3rd party. It works fine and we loaded our code into SVN as usual but when we grab and update and build we get errors saying it cannot find the new dll. The references to the dll are there, but the dll isn't in the bin folder. We'd have to place it in the new location manually.

What can do we need to do to make this external dll behave like all the others? Will we always have to manually move it from now on?

We're using Visual Studio as our IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're using NuGet to download dll's. Check to see if there is a `packages.config` file in project folder and `packages` folder in solution folder.

If that is the case then you either have to get new dll from the same NuGet server, or have your own NuGet server (like Nexus Repository Manager) that would host some packages, and proxy all the other from the nuget.org. You would have to learn how to make a NuGet package, but it's not all that hard.

Alternatively have the dll available to devs in some other way so that they can copy the files manually.